# Protools/Logic compatability

Tags: file, compatibility

Hi,

I am interested in knowing whether or not music composed on Logic will have any issues being dumped onto a Protools LE 9 system. In the past, we found out that omf's from Nuendo 4 could not be read by Protools LE8. I did post this query on SSD and found out that I was not alone when having encountered this problem. Different people offered different solutions but the general consensus was that a converter of sorts such as a Pro Converter was required.

Now, not all music files from Logic will be in an omf format, most likely wave as tghat is what I am recommending. But if anyone has encountered any compatibility issues between the 2, I would appreciate knowing about them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do yourself a favour and expect all sorts of problems. I think the two DAWs being severely incompatible with each other is part of both companies' marketing strategy. Print stems from session start with as much automation applied as you can afford, then import.. I don't mean to sound negative, just think this is the shortest path to getting the work done..

Answer (score 1):

One of the big issues with Nuendo->PT is the interleaved vs. non-interleaved stereo files.  My guess is that issue will exist for Logic->PT transfers.   As i understand, PT is the only  DAW using separate L and R files.  As Georgi.m said, expect more problems, but OMF will not handle the stereo file issue.