# Transferring work between DAWs

Tags: omf, transfer

When transferring between DAWs with OMFs or different facilities without your usual plugins, what procedures do you take?

Just trying to gather ideas on how to work on design and mixing of some short films that I will need to transfer between systems and what things people do.

Do you wait until the final mix to add effects or do you burn them in, in the hope you won't be asked to change the reverb or such?

Answer (score 1):

This is a question that has come up a few times on SSD. I had a terrible experience/reality check when I was working on Nuendo 4 and then tried to transfer the OMF's from the Nuendo on to Protools 8. Protools would not read the OMF. We didn't have the Proconverter plug-in so we had to start from scratch.

Check out the answers I got from this link:

[Protools/Logic compatability](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/9135/protools-logic-compatability)

It seems that transferring work between DAW's can be problematic unless you have a conversion program available to you.

Answer (score 1):

I run between three different systems just about every day, each has different plugins and versions of Pro Tools.  Here are a few ideas from my own experiences.

1) Buy extra plugins for another system. Too expensive, I wouldn't bother.

2) If you want to keep your effects you can export them(individually) from your Primary DAW and they will retain the effects from the plugins. Then move them to the new system. This also helps to build your own library.

3) Internal Laybacks for each track and export. You'll have your dialog, music, and effects on separate tracks, but editing them in great detail will be rather difficult.

4) This will sound insane, but it works. Use only the basic plugins that each system has. Just about every sound designer I know would probably shoot me if they read that.

5) Do as much as you can from one system. If you have multiple individuals working on separate computers I would delegate a specific job to each one. Dialog for John Doe, Sound Effects for George, music for Yoda and final mix for the man with all the plugins.  This keeps you from having to worry about which Mac/PC has the right plugins as they would bounce out their own track.

Hope that was some help, bedtime.

CA

Comment: @Craig good info and a great help. I'll be doing everything on the shorts, but at home I prefer to work and only have Audition and in the studio I have PT9. Doing everything while the director is with you in the studio is problematic and I'm slowly organising the work so that I can get the fiddly bits done without him continually asking where such and such sound is when I've muted it so as to concentrate on another sound. Which is why I want to swap between DAWS so as to get some bits out of the way without the director interupting to ask for changes while I'm on another task.